# select multiple objects using one linq query in entity framwork 6

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following linq queries:

```
   Var q1 = (from t1 in context.Table1
             where column = value
             select t1).FirstOrDefault();



   Var q2 = (from t2 in context.Table2
             where column = value
             select t2).FirstOrDefault();
```

As far as I understand, the above `linq` statements will call the `database` two times to get the table data but I want to write the `linq` query in such a way to get both the tables data in a single database call. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by selecting to anonymous type:

```
Var q = (from t1 in context.Table1
         where t1.column == value
         select t1
         )
         .Select(t1 => new {
             t1 = t1,
             t2 = context.Table2
                 .FirstOrDefault(t2 => t2.column == value);
         })
         .FirstOrDefault();
var t1 = q.t1;
var t2 = q.t2;
```

This way it will make one query from this all. I simplified a bit the query part to obtain t2 item, but there is not obstacle to use the one you wrote.

Comment: how can I test this by debugging?

Comment: Wat do you mean by testing this? You mean checking if this produces indeed one query? To check this instead of FirstOrDefault method at the very end of the whole query use ToString method to check sql code generated. DbContext class offers Log property - you may bind to it to see queries sent to db.

Comment: will check that...i am getting `A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause` in the first `t1` table query..

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I editted my answer to fix that. To be honest I am more used to linq method syntax than this from...select. Please check it if it works and in case not I will present the solution in the method like form which should definitely work.

Comment: Add this line at the start of your code to view the SQL generated by EF, to prove only a single query in produced: `db.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);`

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: This is not possible

Although both queries hitting the same DB but they are working on different tables, 
think about it as you are creating normal SQL statement, you will not be able to combine this tow queries in only one

Comment: it is possible using `DataSet` and `stored procedures` but not in `entity framework/linq`, it would be great if you can explain this..

Comment: What i meant is that the normal SQL statement, as linq is converted to sql statements, so the rule is "if I can query it I can Linq it" is you can say so :)

Answer (score 0):

Correct.

You can however use Entity Framework.Extended to do bulk queries though if you don't mind adding an extension.

See: [github Link](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Future-Queries)

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to load related entities using `Include()` method of EF.

// Load all blogs, all related posts, and all related comments

```
var blogs1 = context.Blogs 
                   .Include(b => b.Posts.Select(p => p.Comments)) 
                   .ToList();
```